# UIImage does not showing

Tags: objective-c

I am using following code to convert base64 string to uiimmage and also getting NSDAta but
i am unable to get image.please check following code.

base64String //contaning base64 string

```
 NSData *imageData = [base64String dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 UIImage *ret = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`UIImage` does not directly recognize base64 encoded data. Check [Base64 encoding options on the Mac and iPhone](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) for information on base64 decoding in iOS. It has `NSData+Base64` category for parsing base64 string into `NSData`.